# Sabre OTA_AirBook soap request

Tags: soap, soapui, sabre

I have problem with soap request for OTA_AirBook on sabre, I can use SessionRequestRQ to get the binary security code.

This is my request

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="2.0">
      <eb:From>
        <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
      </eb:From>
      <eb:To>
        <eb:PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">DEFAULT</eb:PartyId>
      </eb:To>
      <eb:CPAId>XXXX</eb:CPAId>
      <eb:ConversationId>possetrips-1438312976</eb:ConversationId>
      <eb:Service eb:type="OTA">OTA_AirBookLLSRQ</eb:Service>
      <eb:Action>OTA_AirBookLLSRQ</eb:Action>
      <eb:MessageData>
        <eb:MessageId>mid:20150731-105346@DEFAULT</eb:MessageId>
        <eb:Timestamp>2015-07-31T03:54:00</eb:Timestamp>
      </eb:MessageData>
    </eb:MessageHeader>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\\/SessMgr:1\\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\\/ACPCRTC!ICESMSLB\\/CRT.LB!-3507395987210104192!32122!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <OTA_AirBookRQ Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <OriginDestinationInformation>
        <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2015-08-10T06:00:00" FlightNumber="1887" NumberInParty="1" Status="NN" ResBookDesigCode="W">
          <DestinationLocation LocationCode="JFK"/>
          <MarketingAirline Code="B6" FlightNumber="1184"/>
          <OriginLocation LocationCode="MCO"/>
        </FlightSegment>
      </OriginDestinationInformation>
    </OTA_AirBookRQ>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And The Response for this request is

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
      <eb:From>
        <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">DEFAULT</eb:PartyId>
      </eb:From>
      <eb:To>
        <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
      </eb:To>
      <eb:CPAId>XXXX</eb:CPAId>
      <eb:ConversationId>possetrips-1438312976</eb:ConversationId>
      <eb:Service eb:type="OTA">OTA_AirBookLLSRQ</eb:Service>
      <eb:Action>OTA_AirBookLLSRS</eb:Action>
      <eb:MessageData>
        <eb:MessageId>c1b7737a-e817-4c33-b418-f4b8a605f2cd@176</eb:MessageId>
        <eb:Timestamp>2015-07-31T03:54:41</eb:Timestamp>
        <eb:RefToMessageId>mid:20150731-105346@DEFAULT</eb:RefToMessageId>
      </eb:MessageData>
    </eb:MessageHeader>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTC!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3507395987210104192!32122!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap-env:Header>
  <soap-env:Body>
    <OTA_AirBookRS Version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01">
      <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
        <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2015-07-30T22:54:41-05:00">
          <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
            <stl:Message code="0100">INVALID BOARD POINT</stl:Message>
            <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:ShortText>
          </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
        </stl:Error>
      </stl:ApplicationResults>
    </OTA_AirBookRS>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Did I do something wrong with the request ? or I missed some configuration ?

I use https://sws3-crt.cert.sabre.com for endpoint

Answer (score 0):

This response occurs when the boardpoint is invalid, or there is no boardpoint indicated for a flight with multiple stops. 
You also seem to have multiple different flight numbers on the request. Is there  a different marketing and operating Flight number. Check that...

Comment: what should i do after book air segment response success ?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the flight number here to avoid ambiguous boarding point:

```
MarketingAirline Code="B6" FlightNumber="1184"
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you must have run OTA_AIRPrice service as well. Because in OTA, pricing an itinerary is compulsory before running the booking service.

Better to run enhanceairbook service which is a combination of air price and air book both. This will also save your cost of hitting the web service.

Comment: this is incorrect. AirBook reserves seats so will generally be run before the AirPrice call.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "**ArrivalDateTime**" also in your **FlightSegment** after "**DepartureDateTime**", this might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error today when calling enhanced air book with a segment where the operating airline and marketing airlines were different. It took me a while to figure out what was going on.

My problem was, in the bargain finder max response, I was always pulling the flight number from the OperatingAirline element. However, the flight number you pass into enhanced air book needs to be the FlightNumber from the attribute in the FlightSegment element.